# Парсинг страницы java

Tags: java, jsoup

Как я могу запарсить полную веб страницу если там имеется кнопка "Показать еще"? Парсю с помощью jsoup. На скрине показаны атрибуты кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте jQuery вместе с jsoup

Comment: @michael_best интересное предложение. jQuery портировали под яву?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что на кнопку нацеплены ивенты. Выполняются подобные действия явно на js-e.
Варианты работы:

1. Эмулировать браузер с поддержкой js (selenium webdriver или HtmlUnit)
2. Выполнить js-код в ява машине (Rhino)
3. Распарсить js, вытащить из него запрос и в ручную запрашивать следующие данные